# Preparing for The Split - using URLFOR

Tags: formula

I tried to post this in the Salesforce developer forums, but when I hit 'Submit' I just get a bunch of HTML code.

I have this formula

```
HYPERLINK("https://customname.naXX.visual.force.com/apex/create_document?CF00Ni000000EOMhO="&Id&"&CF00Ni000000EOMhO_lkid="&Id&"&scontrolCaching=1&retURL=%2F"&Id&"&sfdc.override=1", "Create Proposal", "_self")
```

and I want replace the guts of it with URLFOR, so I tried this:

```
HYPERLINK(
      URLFOR($Page.create_document,
                     Id ,
       [CF00Ni000000EOMhO=Id,
   CF00Ni000000EOMhO_lkid=Id,
          scontrolCaching=1,
                 retURL=URLFOR($Action.Quote.View, Id),
            sfdc.override=1]
               )
      , "Create Proposal", "_self"
     )
```

When I save this, I get this error:

> Error: Function MAP may not be used in this type of formula

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Not sure about the map part, but change `"../apex/create_document"` to `$Page.create_document`.

Comment: Also, you should change the `retURL` to `{!URLFOR($Action.MyObjectType__c.View, Id)}`.

Comment: Adrian, I changed the code as follows: 'HYPERLINK(
          {!URLFOR($Page.create_document,
                         Id ,
           [CF00Ni000000EOMhO=Id,
       CF00Ni000000EOMhO_lkid=Id,
              scontrolCaching=1,
                       retURL={!URLFOR($Action.Quote.View, Id)},
                sfdc.override=1]
                   )
          }, "Create Proposal", "_self"
         )' but now get a syntax error

Comment: Also I think in that context you don't need to use the `{!}` syntax. That might be your issue...

Comment: Now I get a new error - Field $Page.create_document does not exist. Check spelling. Please review the original code at the top of the posting - it holds the updates.  The "UPDATE" section below is outdated. @AdrianLarson

Comment: I guess for some reason that global variable is not accessible from a formula. :(

Comment: Just switch back then to '/apex/create_document'.

Comment: `URLFOR` can't be used in formula fields; from doc "This function is only available in custom buttons, links, s-controls, and Visualforce pages."  In what context are you using this formula?

Comment: D'oh.. it's a formula field!  Can I use it in a JavaScript button?